# How to override a method in parent class and execute it in child class?

Tags: java, overriding, super, superclass

ì'm trying to learn about override and super class, what i would like to do is override the method in the parent when it is called. And instead execute the one in the child class. How would i do this? it is for a java controlled plc.

```
public class BIhcs_IO extends BComponent implements Runnable {

//Example of a created property for a PLC IO
public static final Property bool_1 = newProperty(Flags.EXECUTE_ON_CHANGE | Flags.OPERATOR | Flags.SUMMARY, ((BBoolean)((BValue)BBoolean.TYPE.getInstance())).getBoolean(), BFacets.tryMake(null));
public boolean getBool_1() { return getBoolean(bool_1); }
public void setBool_1(boolean v) { setBoolean(bool_1, v, null); }

public static final Action execute = newAction(Flags.ASYNC, null);
public void execute() { invoke(execute, null, null); }


@Override
public Type getType() { return TYPE; }
public static final Type TYPE = Sys.loadType(BIhcs_IO.class);


public BComponent getComponent() {
    return this;
}

public void started() throws Exception {
}

//When the Property bool_1 changes it wil execute the doExecute() method below
public void changed(final Property prop, final Context cx) {
    super.changed(prop, cx);
    if (!this.isRunning()) {
        return;
    }
    if (Flags.isExecuteOnChange((BComplex) this, (Slot) prop)) {
        this.execute();
    }
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Source BProgram did not override run(). Exiting thread.");
}

//This is called when a property changes value. When this is called, instead of executing this i want to execute the code in BIhcsMain()
public void doExecute() throws Exception {
   setDebug_1("called parent")
}

public void stopped() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Below is the child class. So when the doExecute() in the parent is called i want to override it and execute it in the child class. so the only output would be "called child"

```
public class BIhcsMain extends BIhcs_IO {

@Override
public void doExecute(){
setDebug_2("called child");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - your code should actually do this, if you add the semicolons `;` at the end of the `setString()` calls to make it compile. In which way does your code not do what you expect?

Comment: I edited my code example to be a bit more clearer. if you can have a look it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the method has the same signature

1. same name
2. accepts same type of parameters in the same order (not name of parameters just types and order is checked)

It will be overriden. As you have typed it is correct and will be overriden.

If you make

```
parentClass parent = new childClass()
parent.doExecute() -> the children method will get executed
```

- Keep in mind method return type is not part of method signature, therefore not checked.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do i create this instance in the parent class or the child? and the "paren.doExecute()" where do i call this? do i place it in the doExecute() of the parent?

Comment: this code of instance creation and execution would normaly go outside of those 2 classes. Search how to execute a java program and implement a public static void main method

Comment: I left out code so the example would be clear. But the code is for a java driven plc where each time an input is triggered an onChange event goes off which call the parents doExecute(). the parent class is a runnable thread so creating a static void main is not possible.. any idea how to do it without the instance creation?

Comment: don't know exactly how to implement something not shown. however it should work as your code will anyways do the override

Comment: i still wasnt able to get it to work, i added a better example of my code. if you could have a look it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Technically it just needs a [compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) signature, not the same signature - raw types are compatible with parameterized types, for example.