# How to override method in parent class and execute it in the child class?

Tags: java, overriding, parent-child

I have to use an 3th party library to create a java driven plc. in this library you have to define the IO's etc and then you will auto generate some code to acces the IO. this will generate a lot of code which i want to split up to keep readable.

The BIhcs_Io class is where everything on the event driven plc is executed. Each time a value of a property changes (see example below of property) it will run the doExecute() method.

What i want to do is that when this method is called, instead i want to execute it on the child class.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class BIhcs_IO extends BComponent implements Runnable {

//Example of a created property for a PLC IO
public static final Property bool_1 = newProperty(Flags.EXECUTE_ON_CHANGE | Flags.OPERATOR | Flags.SUMMARY, ((BBoolean)((BValue)BBoolean.TYPE.getInstance())).getBoolean(), BFacets.tryMake(null));
public boolean getBool_1() { return getBoolean(bool_1); }
public void setBool_1(boolean v) { setBoolean(bool_1, v, null); }

public static final Action execute = newAction(Flags.ASYNC, null);
public void execute() { invoke(execute, null, null); }


@Override
public Type getType() { return TYPE; }
public static final Type TYPE = Sys.loadType(BIhcs_IO.class);


public BComponent getComponent() {
    return this;
}

public void started() throws Exception {
}

//When the Property bool_1 changes it wil execute the doExecute() method below
public void changed(final Property prop, final Context cx) {
    super.changed(prop, cx);
    if (!this.isRunning()) {
        return;
    }
    if (Flags.isExecuteOnChange((BComplex) this, (Slot) prop)) {
        this.execute();
    }
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Source BProgram did not override run(). Exiting thread.");
}

//This is called when a property changes value. When this is called, instead of executing this i want to execute the code in BIhcsMain()
public void doExecute() throws Exception {
   setDebug_1("called parent")
}

public void stopped() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Below is the child class that extends the parent class. Each time the doExecute() in the parent is called i want to override it and execute the one in the child class instead.

```
public class BIhcsMain extends BIhcs_IO {

@Override
public void doExecute(){
setDebug_2("called child");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the way how you override a class or method. Just instantiate <i>BIhcsMain</i> like <code>BIhcs_IO bio = new BIhcsMain()</code> and you're good to go.

Comment: thank you for replying! where do i need to instantiate "BIhcs_IO bio = new BIhcsMain()", im not too experienced with java, do i instantate it in the parents doExecute()?

Comment: you have to instantiate it where you have to call the method. You can check out following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: This seems to be mostly a repost from your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955862/how-to-override-a-method-in-parent-class-and-execute-it-in-child-class#comment116614763_65955862). Could you elaborate more on what is still unclear, and what the differences are to that question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override a method in parent class and execute it in child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955862/how-to-override-a-method-in-parent-class-and-execute-it-in-child-class)

Comment: @Hulk well i'm just having problems implementing it within the code provided above. i tried multiple suggestions from websites and from my previous post. but for some reason  i just dont get the expected output printed by my child class. the problem with this plc library is that code isnt executed in the IDE so i cant debug properly. if someone can edit my code to show me how it should be done it would be greatly appreciated!